# How to prevent Repeater in UpdatePanel from changing values if exception is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` project. I have `Update Panel` and within this panel I have `Repeater` with several nested  repeaters inside it. So my markup looks like this:

```
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpProducts" 
                     UpdateMode="Always"
                     runat="server">
          <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAllocate"/>
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RpUserNameAndProductName" 
                  runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  ..
                  <asp:Repeater ID="RpProductDescription" 
                         runat="server">
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                     //sonme data
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    //some data
                 </ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:Repeater ID="AnotherRepeater" 
                         runat="server">
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                     //sonme data
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    //some data
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
          <asp:button id="btnAllocate"
              text="Allocate"
              usesubmitbehavior="false"
              onclick="btnAllocate_Click"
              runat="server"/>
```

A little confusing markup maybe but the idea is that when I click `btnAllocate` I want to get the values from some textboxes of the nested repeater which I populate at the beginning from the database and then based on their value calculate and set the value of another textbox which initially is empty untill the user decides that he wants the system to do the allocation for him.

So when I enter in the `btnAllocate_Click` event in code behind I have :

```
     try
     {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in RpUserNameAndProductName.Items)
        {
            Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("RpProductDescription")
            foreach (RepeaterItem innerItem in innerRepeater.Items)
            { 
              //here I collect the values and calculate/set the empty text box value
              TextBox txtSomeCalculatedBox = (TextBox)innerItem.FindControl("txtCalculated");
              txtSomeCalculatedBox.Text = //here I execute DB query
            }

            Repeater anotherInnerRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("AnotherRepeater")
            foreach (RepeaterItem aInnerItem in anotherInnerRepeater .Items)
            { 
              //here I collect the values and calculate/set the empty text box value
            }
        }
     }    
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       //How to stop the values from being updated?
     }
```

So basically this is where I'm confused. In order to calculate the new value I need to execute DB queries based on the information that I fetch from the Repeaters so there's room for errors. How ever If the first `foreach` goes well and the error is thrown from the second or third and so on the repeaters are updated with the newly calculated values. It's logical since I set the value inside the foreach where I get the control.

so what I want to do is if I get in the `catch` block (an excpetion is thrown) just to stop the update panel from partially update panel/the repeaters from updating the information.

Comment: I admit I may not fully understand the problem, but you should probably separate the updating logic from the displaying logic. First, collect all the values that you need for the update, pass them to the algorithm (there, perform the update in a transaction or something), catch any exceptions and display the current state (whether it was changed or not) to the user.

Comment: @Pafka you get it right. In fact I was thinking of doing something like this but I'm pretty sure there has to be another way. Something which I consider to be a workaround is to collect the old values and if I go to the `catch` block ro bind the repeaters with them. But it's complicated as it is and if I had even more data moving back and forth it would be just a giant waste of time since I hope my code won't throw exceptions very often :)